# find in string specific information

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a string and would like to find something:

String example:

```
INSERT INTO #__users VALUES("XXXX","First User","admin","69");
```

How can I find numerical id?
Where XXX - is any number.

Comment: What would be the result you're looking for? you want to locate XXXX or id created in database maybe?

Comment: do you mean the ID of the row you inserted? What are you using to insert it? PDOhas the following: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: We still don't know what you really want to find. Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `preg_match` function to get the value with this regex:

```
^INSERT\s+INTO\s+#\S+\s+VALUES\("([^"]+)
```

**REGEX**:

- `^` - Beginning of the string (can be beginning of a line if you add a `m` flag)
- `INSERT` - literal string `INSERT`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace symbols
- `INTO` - literal `INTO`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace symbols
- `#\S+`- Literal `#` followed by 1 or more non-whitespace symbols
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace symbols
- `VALUES\("` - literal `VALUES("`
- `([^"]+)` - A capturing group matching 1 or more characters other than `"` (you may use `\d+` instead if you only have digits here).

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yV1dA3/1). The string you need is in captured group 1, as `[^"]+` will safely match everything but a double quote. In case it only contains digits, use `\d+`: `^INSERT\s+INTO\s+#\S+\s+VALUES\("(\d+)`. In case the string does not appear at the beginning of a string/line, remove `^`.

```
$re = '/^INSERT\s+INTO\s+#\S+\s+VALUES\("([^"]+)/'; 
$str = "INSERT\nINTO #__users\nVALUES(\"9999\",\"First User\",\"admin\",\"69\");"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/rfa0QH)